# Does Reboot command invoke scripts in /etc/rc0.d/ directory?

Tags: scripts, shutdown, reboot, runlevel

I need to kill some services when shutdown/reboot my Linux server, but I am not sure how Reboot command works.

To my understanding, /etc/rc0.d/ scripts will be invoked when system is shutdown, while the /etc/rc6.d/ scripts will be invoked when system is rebooted.

But according to this link: https://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot, reboot command also call shutdown command except when running on level 0 and 6, so does this mean /etc/rc0.d/ scripts are also invoked when reboot command is run ?

Do I only need to put the service kill script into /etc/rc0.d/ and /etc/rc1.d/ ? Or does it also need to be in /etc/rc6.d/ to make sure the service is stopped when reboot ?

Edit: Add my server configuration. Currently running Redhat, varying from 6.x to 7.2.

Comment: Each init script file has lines like these : " # Default-Start:     S
\n# Default-Stop:      0 1 6" these are the default start and stop runlevels . I think when you create a init script , the systemd automatically creates symlinks in the rcX directories.

Comment: You can use "0 6 " for #Default stop of your script.

Comment: In my system the contents of /etc/rc0.d and /etc/rc6.d is exactly the same. So as I know each init script which is to be executed when shutting down , has runlevel 0 and 6 in the Default stop . So looks like there are no difference in rebooting and shutting down from the systemd's perspective.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to kill some processes the way you want when you're shutting down , you can write two simple scripts as follows :

```
#Shutdown.sh
killall blah blah blah
init  0
```

and

```
#Reboot.sh
killall blah blah blah
init 6
```

and make some aliases in the `.bashrc` file of each user you log-in as :

```
alias shutdown_custom="Shutdown.sh"
alias reboot_custom="Reboot.sh"
```

and run those commands each time you want to reboot ( or shutdown)

But if you insist to use a init script , you can put your script in the `/etc/init.d` directory and issue the following command (with super-user permission) :

```
update-rc.d script-name enable 0 6
```

But be aware that you should mention the runlevels in the header of your script . For example this can be found for most linux services :

```
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
```

In my system the contents of `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` is exactly the same , so looks like shutting down and rebooting is the same from the systemd's perspective.

If anybody has a better solution I'm glad to hear.